# Can Irms be ignored if using Isat of an inductor

Tags: inductor

I have got the following parameters for a buck regulator and am attempting to find a suitable inductor:

```
Vi = 3.6
Vo = 1.8
Imax = 1.5
Fsw = 56000
Iripple = 0.45
```

Plugging all these into the inductance value formula:

```
L = ((Vin - Vout) * Vout) / (Vin * Fsw * Iripple)
L = 35.714
```

I know I've got to consider the current ratings of the inductor (with the peak current of `Imax + (Iripple / 2 ) = 1.725A`). If I use this 1.725A and ensure the peak saturation of an inductor is above this (by some safety margin as well), do I still have to consider the RMS current of the inductor. If so, what minimum values should I be requiring considering the above parameters and how do I calculate them?

Answer (score 1):

$$ Irms = Imax  \sqrt{1 + (\frac{Iripple}{12 \times Imax})^2} $$
for a triangular wave (the type from continuous current mode).